# How to design desktop application with modern look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, desktop-application, look-and-feel

I want to create platform independent desktop application with modern look and feel (Simmilar to github desktop application). Is it possible to design desktop application with same kind of look and feel that the github desktop application is providing using **java** ?

Please see github windows application first for reference. Because I already know awt and swing in java, but I don't think we can create same look and feel with awt or swing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same L&F depends on using library's internals.

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can!

You can make your own custom [`LookAndFeel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/LookAndFeel.html) [[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/)] for your applications. Or you can look at one of the ones already available on your computer to see if it's "modern" enough for you:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()));
```

Comment: And also he can check out the L&F's available for download. 1+

Comment: I googled for *github windows application* and it seems to have a brand-new metro UI. While I believe this is possible to implement in Swing, I doubt there's a ready `LookAndFeel` like that. It's bound to be created sooner or later though.

Comment: @Tom Maybe the OP will be the first to create it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to apply the [Synth look and feel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synth_Look_and_Feel) to your swing application, then you are able to completely redesign your widgets with a xml file so you don't have to write additional code. Nearly every attribute of a Swing widget can be configured.

```
final SynthLookAndFeel laf = new SynthLookAndFeel();

try {
    laf.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/your/style.xml"), this.getClass());
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
} catch (final UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```